# How to Run PC-Lint on only locally modified files(Not commited on Server of SVN)

Tags: bash, shell, grep, lint, pc-lint

I am trying to write script to run PC-Lint Static analyzer tool on only locally modified files by user and not on whole project.

For that I need to run `Lint` command on all locally modified files

using svn status

```
 svn status -u | grep -w M
```

command I get list of locally modified files with its full path

For Example if locally modified file is `asn1_common_elements.c`, the above `svn` command will give output as
 M            10014   \Implementations\asn1der\src\asn1_common_elements.c

now I need to take only filename `asn1_common_elements.c` and put it with `LINT` command as `LINT asn1_common_elements.log` (instead of `.c` need to change to `.log`)
How can I achieve this?

Comment: What is the output of  `svn status -u | grep -w M ` don't think it will give a list of files as you mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Makefile's ability to only let the compiler to compile only the changed files.

Do something like this in the Makefile:

```
# Create object from C source code
file.o: file.c
    gcc                -c $(CFLAGS) -o $@
    wine lint-nt.exe   file.c
```

Now the file.c will get analysed only when it is changed.